# Forge for Minecraft 1.8.1 says I have to run MC 1.8.1 manually first (which I've already done)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I've looked everywhere, and I can't seem to find any way to fix the issue I'm having. I found a version of Forge for 1.8, I downloaded it, but when I tried to run the client, it said I have to run Minecraft 1.8 manually first, which I've already done. Again, I downloaded it and it said the same thing.

Can anyone help?

Important Info (maybe):
Minecraft Version: 1.8.1
Launcher Version: 1.6.5

Comment: have you tried running 1.8 as your saying your version is 1.8.1, it's possible (considering Forge for 1.8 is still early Beta) Forge actually means 1.8 and not 1.8.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a version of forge for 1.8.1 by the looks of it.

Run the 1.8 (*not 1.8.1*) of Minecraft and it should work.

Comment: How do I run 1.8? Do I have to install a different version of Minecraft? Will I lose my worlds if I do that, or are they saved on my profile?

Comment: The worlds are saved to the profile, I assume you have the 1.8 forge installer saved on your desktop. Then go to your launcher and where it says edit profile go to the dropdown that says `Use version:` and select "release 1.8". Run Minecraft once and then you an install forge, it should make a new profile called Forge <version> or similar. Once you've run it to check that it works go back to the Defualt profile and change `Use version:` to release 1.8.1.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done what you asked, and it worked.

Comment: Mark the question as correct with the check mark

Comment: I have one last issue. I've downloaded and placed two mods in the "mod" file, and they aren't working. They're both mods that are supposed to work with Forge, so I'm not exactly sure what I should do.    This is one of them: http://www.minecraftmods.com/treecapitator/

Comment: Are you putting the zip files in there?

Comment: Yes, I put the zip files in there.

Comment: The treecaptitor mod seems to be for 1.7.
Try this list: http://modlist.mcf.li/version/1.8.

Answer (score 3):

Go into the Minecraft Launcher. Edit your profile and look for [Version Selection] > Use version: And choose for version 1.8. Let it download by clicking play.
Close the game and re-run the Forge Installer. It should work now.

Answer (score -1):

Remove your 1.8.1 version of minecraft, it is located usually at:
"%appdata%\roaming\.minecraft\versions"

Try re-run forge setup, if it wont work then just use 1.8

1.8 forge for windows (installer included) -> http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.8-11.14.0.1281-1.8/forge-1.8-11.14.0.1281-1.8-installer-win.exe